# Doing an overload function when input is 0

Tags: python, overloading

I trying to do a program where the user can input temperature in Fahrenheit and it is calculated in Celsius only quitting the loop if the temperature is just right.

The program is working but the last bit is to make an overloaded function if the user inputs 0. If user inputs 0 the program should create a random number and send it back to the `while` loop. I cannot get this to work or figure out where to put the overload. Here is the code as it looks now:

```
import random
celsius = 0

def fahr_to_cel(temp):
    # function that receives value in fahrenheit and returns value in celsius
    global celsius
    celsius = round((temp - 32) * 5/9, 2)
    return celsius

# welcome message to user
print ("Hello and welcome to your personal sauna.")

while celsius < 82 or celsius > 87:
  try:
    fahr_to_cel(int(input("Please write a desired temperature in fahrenheit: ")))
    if celsius < 82:
      print (str(celsius) + " degrees celsius, that is probably a bit too cold")
    elif celsius > 87:
      print (str(celsius) + " degrees celsius, that is probably a bit too hot")
  except:
    print ("Something went wrong, you might have written letters!")

# output the actual temperature in celsius
print ("Your temperature is now " + str(celsius) + " degrees celsius and perfect for a good sauna!")
input("Press any key to continue...")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can clean up a few things. Its generally best to avoid using globals. Your function doesnt need to know about the celsius variable it just needs to return a value and you can assign that return to celsius in the main code.

You can also have your function check if the temp value is 0 and if so generate a random temp between 100 and 200 for example.

I have also used an infinite loop here and the break condition is in the else statement since if the value is not less then 82 and not greater than 87 then its the right temp

```py
import random


def fahr_to_cel(temp):
    # function that receives value in fahrenheit and returns value in celsius
    if temp == 0:
        temp = random.randint(100, 200)
    return round((temp - 32) * 5 / 9, 2)


# welcome message to user
print("Hello and welcome to your personal sauna.")
while True:
    try:
        celsius = fahr_to_cel(int(input("Please write a desired temperature in fahrenheit: ")))
        if celsius < 82:
            print(str(celsius) + " degrees celsius, that is probably a bit too cold")
        elif celsius > 87:
            print(str(celsius) + " degrees celsius, that is probably a bit too hot")
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("Something went wrong, you might have written letters!")

# output the actual temperature in celsius
print("Your temperature is now " + str(celsius) + " degrees celsius and perfect for a good sauna!")
input("Press any key to continue...")
```

Comment: Perfect this was a great solution. Thank you!